# Get matrix element through a vector of indices

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

I'm trying to parse the coordinates of a matrix from a vector to retrieve an element.

Data:

```
m <- matrix(1:25, ncol = 5)
v <- c(2,3)
```

I'm basically trying to get the element`m[2,3]`, in that case the value 12, by parsing the vector as coordinates:

`m[v]`

but all I get is `NA`. I have tried `m[paste(v, collapse="\",\""]`, which also did not work.

I know I could use

`m[paste(v[1]), paste(v[2])]`

but I'm trying to find a more elegant solution.

Any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: There is no need for *paste*: `m[ v[ 1 ], v[ 2 ] ]`

Comment: You are right. It turned out I have simplified the example a bit too much. I have posted an updated question here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74992627/get-matrix-element-through-a-vector-of-indices)

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
> m[matrix(v, 1)]
[1] 12
```

or just

```
> m[t(v)]
[1] 12
```

Comment: Even `matrix(v)` is enough as it will be a column matrix

Answer (score 1):

Few more options:

```
m[v[1], v[2]]
[1] 12

do.call("[", c(list(m), as.list(v)))
[1] 12

m[v[1] + (v[2]-1) * nrow(m)]
[1] 12
```