# Get matrix element through a vector of indices

Tags: r, matrix, coordinates

I have posted a similar question here: [Get matrix element through a vector of indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74983272/get-matrix-element-through-a-vector-of-indices)

However, my example and the data seemed to be too simplified, which did not solve my problem.

The main issue I'm having is that I have rows and columns named through numbers, which seems to complicate things a bit.

```
m <- matrix(1:25, ncol = 5, dimnames = list(c(1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000), c(1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000)))
v <- c(10,100)
```

I'm basically trying to get the element m[10,100], in that case the value 12, by parsing the vector as coordinates:

```
m[v]
m[10,100]
```

results in

```
> Error in m[10,100] : subscript out of bounds
```

while

```
m[paste(v[1]), paste(v[2])]
m["10","100"]
```

works.

How can is parse the vector into coordinates, without accessing each element individually (i.e. `v[1]`, `v[2]`)?

Comment: Because you want to index by the dimension names your indices need to be of class character.  So adapting one of the answers from the post you linked, you can do `m[t(as.character(v))]`.